# how to Embed multiple html pages to one html page using ionic

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic  develop mobile application.

How to Embed multiple html pages to one html page using ionic?

```html
<ion-side-menus>
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-view name="EmbeddedContent"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use div with **ng-include=""**

Example:

```
<div ng-include="'myTemplate.html'"></div>
```